# Rust : Cleanest way to transfert result and catch an error in when calling function?

Tags: rust

in order to learn Rust, I try to create small snippets to apply what we learn in the Rust book and implement good practices.

Have a small function to list content of a repository :

```
use std::{io, fs, path::PathBuf, path::Path};


pub fn get_directory_content(path: &str) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, io::Error> {
    let _path: bool = Path::new(path).is_dir();
    match _path {
        true => {
            let mut result = vec![];
            for file in fs::read_dir(path).unwrap() {
                result.push(file.unwrap().path());
            }
            Ok(result)
        },
        false => Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, " is not a directory")),
    }

    }
```

my goal is to be able to catch the error if the folder does not exist without triggering a panic.

in main.rs :

```
mod utils;

fn main() {
    let directory = "./qsdsqd";
    let test = utils::get_directory_content(directory).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

if directory exist : ok, unwrap is happy. But does anyone know a "trick" for get the content of the error in var test ? Also, can we put the name of a variable in io::ErrorKind::Other to get more precision (here : &path) ?

Next try

```
fn main() {
let directory = "./qsdqsd";
let a = match utils::get_directory_content(directory){
    Err(e) => println!("an error: {:?}", e),
    Ok(c) => println!("{:?}", c),
};
println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

When error, ok, we have message, but here, if we put a correct folder : a "just" print result but content is empty, and we can't say Ok(c) => c for just return Ok content from function :/

Comment: You could return `Result<Vec<PathBuf>, &'static str>` as a starter.

Comment: I would say that returning `Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>` from `main` is a start, along with then returning `Result<Vec<PathBuf>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>` from `get_directory_content()`.  Then `?` should be able to be used to great effect here.  But I'm a bit busy, and can't prototype that out right now.

Comment: I'd like to yield my answer to @Masklinn, his response better answers "Cleanest way". Mine just addresses one of the problems in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have a small function to list content of a repository :

That's already a pretty bad start, because it combines a TOCTOU with unnecessary extra work: if you're checking `is_dir` then trying to read the directory, it's possible for the entry to get deleted or swapped from under you.

This is a shame, since `read_dir` already does exactly what you want:

```rust
pub fn get_directory_content(path: &str) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, io::Error> {
    let mut result = vec![];
    for file in fs::read_dir(path)? {
        result.push(file.unwrap().path());
    }
    Ok(result)
}
```

And you can apply this to the individual entries as well:

```rust
pub fn get_directory_content(path: &str) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, io::Error> {
    let mut result = vec![];
    for file in fs::read_dir(path)? {
        result.push(file?.path());
    }
    Ok(result)
}
```

> When error, ok, we have message, but here, if we put a correct folder : a "just" print result but content is empty, and we can't say `Ok(c) => c` for just return Ok content from function :/

Sure you can, however you still have to do something for the `Err` case: as most things in Rust, `match` is an expression, so all the branches need to return values of the same type... or not return at all:

```rust
    let a = match get_directory_content(directory) {
        Err(e) => {
            println!("an error: {:?}", e);
            return;
        }
        Ok(c) => c,
    };
```

`return` has type `!`, which is Rust's "bottom" type: it's compatible with everything, because `return` does not "terminate", and thus there's npo reason for it to be incompatible with anything.

Alternatively, you could update `main` to return a `Result` as well, though that also requires updating it to return a value:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    let directory = "./.config";
    let a = get_directory_content(directory)?;
    println!("{:?}", a);
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Or even shorter implementation of `get_directory_content`: `fs::read_dir(path)?.map(|e| e.map(|f| f.path())).collect()`. Although I accept the argument that the `for` based version is more readable ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `c` from your `match` statement.

Further, you need to do something in the `Err` case other than just print. What should `a` be in the error case?
I assume that you simply want to end the program, so I inserted a `return`.

```rust
mod utils {
    use std::{fs, io, path::Path, path::PathBuf};

    pub fn get_directory_content(path: &str) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, io::Error> {
        let _path: bool = Path::new(path).is_dir();
        match _path {
            true => {
                let mut result = vec![];
                for file in fs::read_dir(path).unwrap() {
                    result.push(file.unwrap().path());
                }
                Ok(result)
            }
            false => Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, " is not a directory")),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let directory = "./qsdqsd";
    let a = match utils::get_directory_content(directory) {
        Err(e) => {
            println!("an error: {:?}", e);
            return;
        }
        Ok(c) => {
            println!("{:?}", c);
            c
        }
    };
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

```
["./qsdqsd/a.txt"]
["./qsdqsd/a.txt"]
```

---

**DISCLAIMER:** My answer is very much superficial. @Masklinn goes into much more detail about the "cleanest way" and other issues with the given code.

Because this is the accepted answer (at the time of writing), here is how a "cleanest way" version of the code could look like:

```rust
use std::{fs, io, path::PathBuf};

pub fn get_directory_content(path: &str) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, io::Error> {
    let mut result = vec![];
    for file in fs::read_dir(path)? {
        result.push(file?.path());
    }
    Ok(result)
}

fn main() {
    let directory = "./qsdqsd2";
    let a = match get_directory_content(directory) {
        Err(e) => {
            println!("an error: {:?}", e);
            return;
        }
        Ok(c) => c,
    };
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

```
["./qsdqsd/a.txt"]
```

Alternatively, you could have `main()` return a `Result`, which makes this even cleaner:

```rust
use std::{fs, io, path::PathBuf};

pub fn get_directory_content(path: &str) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, io::Error> {
    let mut result = vec![];
    for file in fs::read_dir(path)? {
        result.push(file?.path());
    }
    Ok(result)
}

fn main() -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    let directory = "./qsdqsd";
    let a = get_directory_content(directory)?;
    println!("{:?}", a);
    Ok(())
}
```